# jQuery show/hide 1 at a time

Tags: jquery

I have created something where upon clicking a div/button, it opens a separate div and its contents. I am looking to have all of the non-targeted items close or slide up upon clicking one of the button divs.

Long story short, I want only 1 'target-div' open at a time. How do I accomplish this? (link to fiddle below code)

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {
  var $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));

  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $target.delay(300).slideDown();    

 if($target.is(':visible')){
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
  $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
  return false;
 }  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dNU92/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The following code performs what you want - hiding the other divs that are open when you click another one.

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {
    var $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));

    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $target.delay(300).slideToggle();    


    if($target.is(':visible')){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {  
        $('.target-div:visible').not($(this)).removeClass('open').slideUp();
    }
});
```

The only addition here was:

`$('.target-div:visible').not($(this)).removeClass('open').slideUp();`

Here's your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNU92/13/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to retain the item closing upon clicking the button a second time. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey @rymill2 - just as an extra here you may notice that upon clicking the slideUp() happens almost instantly: you could put a delay here to make it wait for the slideUp animation to finish before then opening the new one. Just make it look a little nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your fiddle, add a slideUp()

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {
  var $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));
  $('.target-div').slideUp();
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $target.delay(300).slideToggle();    

  if($target.is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
      return false;
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery like below...

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dNU92/12/

Add a line like : `$(".target-div:visible").hide()`

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {
  var $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));
  $(".target-div:visible").hide() /// this is the line i have added
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $target.delay(300).slideToggle();    

  if($target.is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
      return false;
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a action inside your click to hide the visible element. This animation works rather nice:

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.target-div:visible').slideUp('normal', function(){ $(this).hide(); });

    var $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));

  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $target.delay(300).slideToggle();    

  if($target.is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
      return false;
  }  
});
```

I used [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNU92/8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.target-div').hide();
$('.button').click(function () {

    var $target

    for (var i=1; i<9; i++){
        $target = $('#div' + i);
        $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');   
    }
   $target = $('#div' + $(this).data('target'));

  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $target.delay(300).slideToggle();    

  if($target.is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $target.slideUp('normal').removeClass('open');
      return false;
  }  
});
```

something like this?